# не корректно отрисовывается select с динамически обновляемыми option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Есть выпадающий список:

```
<select name="my-select">
  <option>...</option>
  <option>...</option>
  <option>...</option>
</select>
```

При нажатии на него, получаю данные ajax-ом запрос, и очищаю и обновляю в нужном **select** необходимые **options**.

Проблема в том что, при нажатии на элемент выпадающего списка, некорректно рассчитывается высота выпадающего меню с доступными **option**.
То есть, если там был один **option** до нажатия, и я нажал и подгрузилось **10 option**,
то выпадающий список с выбором будет с высотой, как для одного поля.

Но если нажать еще раз то данные по размеру выпадающего списка обновляются корректно.

Такое ощущение что обновление размера окна выпадающего списка происходит до выполнения ajax и загрузки новых данных.

Как правильно это сделать?

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('select[name="my-select"]').on("focus",function(e) {
    var myDynamoSelect = $('select[name="my-select"]');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: "name=John&location=Boston",
        success: function ( data ) {

          myDynamoSelect.empty().html(data);
        }
     });


    });
 });
```

Comment: Вы меняете набор опций в уже выпавшем селекте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнять ajax синхронно при помощи async:false

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('select[name="my-select"]').on("focus",function(e) {
    var myDynamoSelect = $('select[name="my-select"]');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: "name=John&location=Boston",
        async:false,
        success: function ( data ) {

          myDynamoSelect.empty().html(data);
        }
     });


    });
 });
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало :) То что надо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете поиграться с ивентами и задержками, но будет не очень красиво. Мне кажется, самое оно будет заранее получить все `option` и подсунуть их в селект ещё при загрузке страницы.

```js
$('select[name="my-select"]').on("mouseup", function() {
  var myDynamoSelect = $('select[name="my-select"]');
  myDynamoSelect.html('<option vslue="1">1</option><option vslue="2">2</option>');
});

$('select[name="my-select2"]').on("focus", function() {
  var myDynamoSelect = $('select[name="my-select2"]')
  setTimeout(function() {
    myDynamoSelect.html('<option vslue="1">1</option><option vslue="2">2</option>');
  }, 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="my-select">
 <option disabled selected="selected">mouseup</option>
</select>

<select name="my-select2">
 <option disabled selected="selected">setTimeout</option>
</select>
```